# What does the "teehee" expression mean?

Tags: tropes

[image: :p]

I'm sure most of you know this phrase, what does it mean? Does it represent stupidity cutey thing that they do? What makes this phrase so popular?

Comment: The instance from *Oregairu* above is likely [a reference to  Peko-chan](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/what-is-the-origin-of-this-facial-expression-with-ones-tongue-sticking-out), which is very common in modern anime.

Comment: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/what-is-the-origin-of-this-facial-expression-with-ones-tongue-sticking-out/3003#3003

Comment: Meta discussion at http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/766/are-these-two-tongue-sticking-out-questions-really-duplicates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that it is of japanese origin though.

*Teehee* is just a cute giggle, pretty common internet slang. More on it can be found at the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Teehee&defid=788143), mainly

> The sound of a giggle. Used by (1) schoolgirls and (2) old geezers
>   pretending to be schoolgirls.

and

> Defintion: 1)The act of joyful giggling. 2)A noise made to convey
>   happiness 3)Presented to imply innocence

Answer (score 8):

The head punching and tongue sticking out makes me think the "teehee" is a translation of てへぺろ ("tehepero"), which has a literal meaning of "teehee tongue-sticking-out". It actually has a recent history as a word in its own right: [this blog post](http://bangin.wordpress.com/2013/12/03/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%B8%E3%81%BA%E3%82%8D-tehepero%E0%B9%91%E2%89%A7%E0%B1%AA%E2%89%A6%E3%81%A6%E3%81%B8%E3%81%BA%E3%82%8D/) and [this crunchyroll news article](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2012/03/03-1/vocab-lesson-strange-yet-cute-tehepero-teaser-website-appears) have some information about it.

Basically, it's the word that goes with teehee+punching head+tongue sticking out, and the meaning is primarily focused on definition 3) that Omega posted - it sweeps under the rug a mistake or ignorance of the speaker with a playful gesture. A Japanese source for this meaning is [this scan of an article about tehepero being Japanese neologism of the year](http://blog.livedoor.jp/seiyumemo/archives/7022095.html), although the expression is likely related to peko-chan (see [What is the origin of this facial expression with one's tongue sticking out?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/)).